# Openai Module Not Found

Tags: python, apache, module, openai-api

OpenAi Module not loading

I have installed the OpenAi module to my raspberry pi and am using some Python code to access it. From the terminal it works fine. I wanted to call the Python code from a PHP page using shell_exec to retrieve the answer. However, the Python code cannot find the openai module, although it finds other modules. I suspect it is a user/permissions/path problem. From terminal, it works, from the PHP web page it does not. Here is the error that is given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/chat-pod.py", line 26, in <module>
    import openai
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'
```

I have tried manipulating the python environment, different permissions, examined apache2 conf files.

Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Checked the related questions and it seemed that question 3 had the most promise. However, adding the steps in that solution still did not correct the "no mudule named openai" error. I added additional paths to $PYTHONPATH but no change there also.

Comment: Update: Got the solution in Related question 3 to work. Now the next task is to ensure the virtual environment is still present on new boot.